# pdomodel: only fech 1 row

Tags: php, pdo

i have a query to execute with db abstraction layer pdomodel .This query returns only 1 row. Which is the easiest way to get the 'RMwin' and 'RBwin' values without executing a foreach? Is there a more direct way of obtaining these values?

```
<?php
require_once 'script/PDOModel.php';
 $pdomodel = new PDOModel();
 /* Step 3: Connect to the database */
 $pdomodel->connect("localhost", "renaud", "password", "test");
 /* Step 4: call PDOModel functions */
 $pdomodel->columns = array("UserID");
   $records = $pdomodel->executeQuery("SELECT RMwin,
                RBwin
       FROM testtable
       WHERE TransDate >= '2019-08-01';");  

           foreach($records as $row)
        {
              echo $row['RMwin'].'<br>'.$row['RBwin'].'<br>;

        }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LIMIT` keyword in your `SQL` statement.

```sql
"SELECT RMwin, RBwin FROM testtable WHERE TransDate >= '2019-08-01' LIMIT 1"
```